# Getting "Authentication credentials were not provided" error when I don't want to require authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a project with JWT authentication in Django Rest Framework. Usually I require user to be authenticated but in the case of GET action (both list and retrieve) I would like everyone to be able to access it with no authentication required.

The code for this functionality is very simple:

```
class GetUserViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):

    # allowed for everyone
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

The permissions are set to allow any but there is probably some inconsistency with default auth class in Settings.py

```
# --------------------------REST-framework--------------------------
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly'
    ],

    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

The last thing that could matter are my endpoints:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", UserViewSet.as_view({"post": "create"}), kwargs={'quantity': 1}),
    path("<int:quantity>/", UserViewSet.as_view({"post": "create"})),
    path("", GetUserViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"})),
    path("<int:pk>/", GetUserViewSet.as_view({"get": "retrieve"})),
    path("<int:pk>/", UserViewSet.as_view({"put": "update", "delete": "destroy"})),
]
```

What I don't understand is that in other app where I have register functionality there is no such an error. I will show you this viewset:

```
class ApiUserViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = ApiUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = ApiUser.objects.all()

    @extend_schema(request=ApiUserSerializer, responses=TokenSerializer)
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        api_user_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        api_user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        api_user = api_user_serializer.save()

        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(api_user)

        token_serializer = TokenSerializer(
            data={
                "access": str(refresh.access_token),
                "refresh": str(refresh)
            }
        )

        token_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        headers = self.get_success_headers(token_serializer.data)

        return Response(token_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

If you have any idea what could be wrong please let me know!

Thank you

Comment: Try removing the permission from settings and setting the permission you want on each ViewSet with this variable: authentication_classes